# Is there a real solution for android emulator?

Tags: android, performance, emulation, android-edittext

I'm trying to program a game for android phones. Anyway I have to check any of my minor changes on my code. But I have only 5MB of file and only using **SurfaceView** to draw not even **GLSurfaceView**(So I think because of **I'm not using OpenGL:3D stuff** and just **drawing bitmaps** it should be faster. I'm not sure because it wasn't fast in C/BorlandC 8D) and android emulator is that much slow It kills me of waiting. **I tried to not use all of my bitmaps so it can upload and install faster.** But **how about FPS** ????? I get 5-10 fps which I need 20 for my game. plus **some times I can't get all the bitmap that should be drawn** by emulator(Example: If I have 10 fps in 5 of that I can't see half of my bitmaps...) I can't check what's going on in my game! So if there is a better way please tell me. I read some peoples are using their **android phone as emulator is that really faster?** If so I'll get one. Some other says **using windows XP is the best way, is there no FPS problem with it?** In that case I have to use virtual machine. Thank you for any reply!

Comment: You need to narrow down the scope of this question.  Seems like you aren't sure which problem needs solving first...

Comment: The android emulator is WAY too slow. Just plug your android device and test on real time.

Comment: The only problem is emulator's performance there is no more problem. I don't have any android device right now. My friends doesn't either. If it really works I'll buy one.

Comment: Buying an Android device is your only solution. Unfortunately the Android emulator is very slow, because it emulates a whole ARM-CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that there is a software named "Bluestacks" it's even supports OpenGL ES and you get all the FPS you want. So it's perfect match for android developers. Of course it's free too:[this is the web site you can download](http://bluestacks.com/) happy coding...

Answer (score 5):

There is a fairly easy option. You can use VirtualBox to run a virtual machine and then install androidx86 (http://www.android-x86.org/) as an operating system. I have tried it myself and the performance is almost perfect.

There is a complete guide here http://androidspin.com/2011/01/24/howto-install-android-x86-2-2-in-virtualbox/

EDIT - once the VM is up and running, you will also need to connect to the VM. Press Alt-F1 and type `netcfg` to get the VM IP (should be 10.0 something). Then on your host machine cd to the android tools directory and type `./adb connect <VM IP>:5555`